# Can I dynamically find all subclasses of a class in powershell

Tags: powershell, metaprogramming

I have an abstract baseclass that I would like a list of all subclasses dynamically (that are currently loaded). However, I have not been able to find a sample of this. I would like something similar to:

```
 $subclasses = [AbstractRule].get-subclasses
```

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enumerate all types in the current application domain, then use [`Type.IsSubclassOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.issubclassof) to find the one's you're interested in:

```
$superType = [AbstractRule]
$subTypes = [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().GetTypes() |Where {$_.IsSubclassOf($superType)}
```

This will also include custom derived types defined using PowerShell classes (if any exist)

---

You could also limit your search to just the assembly that contains `[AbstractRule]`, if you suspect all the subclasses to be in the same:

```
$subTypes = $superType.Assembly.GetTypes() |Where {$_.IsSubclassOf($superType)}
```